# Equations for stress in a hollow prolate spheroid under external pressure

Tags: stresses, pressure-vessel

Are there analytical expressions (functions of geometry and applied pressure) for the stress in a hollow prolate spheroid, like there are expressions for the stress in a hollow sphere/cylinder?

Comment: So, posted on physics as well : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381970/stress-equations-in-a-hollow-prolate-spheroid-under-external-pressure

Comment: Took some digging to find - see section 2.3,p 7.- http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/431706.pdf. It doesn't consider buckling because it's for internally pressurized tanks.